# Cannot resolve class layer-list

Tags: xml, android-layout, layer-list

I tried creating a simple SplashScreen drawable resource file (.xml) with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_red"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_green"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
    <item android:top="20dp" android:left="20dp">
      <bitmap android:src="@drawable/android_blue"
        android:gravity="center" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

but it gives me the following errors:

> Cannot resolve class layer-list
> Cannot resolve class item
> Cannot resolve class bitmap

Is layer-list a deprecated class?

I tried including version 7.3.1 libraries but that didn't solve it.

Answer (score 2):

This only happens when creating your .xml under Layout rather than Drawable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just move your file from layout to drawable. It should fix the issue
"Cannot resolve class item"
"Cannot resolve class bitmap"